# Java vs PHP for implementing the API

Tags: java, php, api, rest, backend

I am building an application that consumes services from the API that I am writing. I am building the frontend in PHP. It is a social networking site. So my question is does it matter if I implement the backend API in Java (using RESTlet) or should I go for a all - PHP solution where everything is in PHP?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider the [php-java-bridge.](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Is there any loss in performance if I implement the API in PHP? The site is expected to have heavy load.

Comment: @Fox That depends mostly on _you_ and your code footprint among many other things.  Many PHP sites have reached critical mass.